# Interface builder added one tab bar button, but not showing up

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I replaced one tab bar button in interface builder. It was "Recent" button, I changed it to "Contacts" button. Now the tab bar button not showing up, but I could click on that position, and action does work. The neighbor unchanged tab bars have no problem though.

I could not find any place to set the visibility of Tab Bar button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you change it to the Contacts button make sure you select the Contacts option from the drop down list of apple provide tab bar buttons - if you type in "Contacts" as the title of a bar button that has been selected as recent - this will cause problems and may be causing the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: the problem still there, I tried to change to other type from the drop down list, such as "Top Rated" and so on. Saw the same result.